# Unable to Consume old messages in the kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

The Producer in Kafka is producing messages, but the consumer is down after consuming the 5th message. After some time the consumer is up, and I want to consume the 6th message, instead of the latest message.

How can I do this?

**Producer.java**

```
public class kafkaProducerRoute extends RouteBuilder{
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {


   from("timer:time?")
            // loop over the route 10 times
            .setBody().constant("Hello, World!") // set the message body to "Hello, World!"
            .to("kafka:hello1?brokers=localhost:9092")  // send the message to a Kafka topic using the Kafka producer endpoint
            .log("Message is produced");



}
```

}

**Consumer.java**

```
    from("kafka:c1?brokers=localhost:9092")

            .log("Received message with offset: ${header." + KafkaConstants.OFFSET + "} - ${body}");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the consumer group comes up again, does it come up with the same old group_id, if yes, then it should continue from where it left, if not, then this is normal as per the default setting for `auto.offset.reset = latest` will always start from the latest offset of the topic

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.offset.reset